# How PowerShell loads the binary module's dependent assemblies?

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-module

I have a PowerShell binary module that has reference to an assembly "X" that I want to NGEN and to use its NI (native image) at runtime.

In the module manifest I added the "X" assembly in the RequiredAssemblies.

Looking in the Fusion Log Viewer I see the following:

1. After Import-Module the assembly "X" fails to load:

   > The operation failed. Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.
2. After calling the first command that needs "X" FusLogViewer shows new record for "X" with Version, Culture, etc. 
   The load now succeeds but it is in the LoadFrom context which prevents loading of its NI.

> LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
>
> WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().

My questions here are:

**1. What is the PowerShell mechanism for loading dependent assemblies?**

**2. Can I somehow load my "X" assembly in Load context in order to use its NI?**

Thank You!
- Dimitar

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a few debugging I found out the following:

When module is in some of the $env:PSModulePath, the loading of the RequiredAssemblies goes through

**1. Assembly.LoadWithPartialName**, which throws the error I observe in the FusionLogViewer, then the algorithm falls back to

**2. Assembly.LoadFrom** resolving the path by using the module's path joined to the assembly name specified as an entry in RequiredAssemblies.

The last loads the assembly in LoadFrom context.

The only way I found to load the assemblies Load context is to put the module in the $PSHome\Modules folder, which is subfolder of the powershell.exe, then to add the module's path to the app domain probing paths, and call LoadWithPartialName from some of the module scripts.

Here is how the script call look like:

```
[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.AppendPrivatePath("Modules\<My Module>")
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('<Assembly Name>') | Out-Null
```

I load the assembly from the script because loading of RequiredAssemblies is called before any of the module scripts, but I update the probing paths from the script itslef, so the assembly is removed from the RequiredAssemblies and is loaded manually.